# how to use org-plus-contrib?

Tags: org-mode, package

I would like to use org-mode's contributed packages:
http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/

**[EDIT] SOLUTION:**

As per answer below:
1) First one should have the elpa packages added.

```
(require 'package)
...
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
...
(package-initialize)
```

This is described [here] in detail.[1](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html)

2) Afterwards, below the lines above, one can add the desired modules like this:

```
(require 'org-checklist)
```

**WARNING**
Some packages may be available in the git-hub repository but not yet in the official repository. (e.g org-eww at the time of writing). 
As such, requiring these will cause errors.

Before adding a requirement, it is reccomended to browse the folder:

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-<DATE>
```

Comment: You need to specify the actual value of "CONTRIB_DIR" instead of the variable name. Suppose you cloned the contributed libraries into `~/.emacs.d/org/contrib`, then you need to replace `CONTRIB_DIR` with `"~/.emacs.d/org/contrib/lisp"`.

Comment: That's what I'm using atm. I cloned the git hub repo and added a require: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/Dropbox/appData/emacs/orgEgit/org-mode/contrib/lisp/").  But I would like to use the org-plus-contrib instead. The problem is that is has a weird file name (date inside the filename) so the same .emacs file that I share between computers won't work on all my machines. Is there a dynamic way to get to that folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`org-plus-contrib` and `org` with `require` or `use-package`](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/org-plus-contrib-and-org-with-require-or-use-package).

Comment: Hello, I have read the post, but the advise there doesn't solve the issue unfortunatley. It is not a duplicate, these two questinos vary sligtly. Please see my edit.

Comment: If the problem is only the name, then you could do something like: `(add-to-list 'load-path (car (file-expand-wildcards "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-*/contrib/lisp")))`.

Comment: If I could get this to work, then this would solve it.  I have tierd: (add-to-list 'load-path (car (file-expand-wildcards "~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-plus-contrib-*")))  But at load it won't find the required libs. Maybe it's because there is a missing forward slash? I tried adding it with (concat ... "/") around the file-expand.. function, but it errors out. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: Try just the `file-expand-wildcards` in the scratch buffer with the path you want to give it and see if you can build the glob to select the file you want.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev Just to make sure: You *are* calling `package-initialize` before `require`ing `org-checklist` and `org-eww` in your init-file, correct?

Comment: adding a hard-file load was not needed. It turns out the org-eww package simply hasn't made it into the elpa repo yet. I updated the question to reflect the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything special. I'm running the org-plus-contrib package from the org elpa repository and can just require any of the packages that are included.

I did look and org-eww is not in the org-plus-contrib I have.(my version is  20150209)

I did a (require 'org-checklist) and evaluated it in my scratch buffer and it loaded fine.

Perhaps your org mode isn't loading properly? It is really important that the org-plus-cntrib package is loaded before any org related functions are called. If you have something which references org before you load the org-plus-contrib package, you end up with a mix of the bundled org mode and then the org-plus-contrib package, which can cause some odd behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to investigate this. It turns out that org-eww is a fresh package that hasn't made it into the elpa repos yet. I was confused between the available org-checklist and the not-available org-eww.

Comment: Not a problem. Actually, I'm only responding to try out the new sx.el package for writing and reading questions on SO sites

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the [online documentation](http://orgmode.org/elpa.html):

> orgmode.org hosts Org ELPA archives.
>
> Add this to your Emacs init file to be able to list the Org mode archives:
>
> (require 'package)
>   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
>
> Then M-x list-packages RET will list both the latest org and org-plus-contrib packages.
>
> org
>       contains the same set of files that are included in GNU Emacs.
>   org-plus-contrib
>       contains these files plus all contribs files, the ones you find in contrib/ from the git repo.

Comment: This answer should be updated to use secure HTTPS `(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)`. Visitor check the link to online documentation.