# org vs org-plus-contrib in Emacs24.4

Tags: org-mode

I am a newbie here, currently I am learning some advanced features of org mode.

I am using Emacs24.4 which has a build in org mode(version 8.2.10, dir "emacs.d/elpa/org-20150608").

I want to use org-plus-contrib so I installed it from orgmode.org/elpa, but after installing, I found it also contains most files in org mode folder. 
I am very confused of how to use this "contrib" folder? Does it means I have two org installed?

What if I just copy the contrib folder from org git repo, where should I put it? and what the configure like?

thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common files you observe are identical so you can simply use `org-plus-contrib` if you wish to use contributed packages.  The `org` package is then unnecessary.  You can put the files anywhere you wish, but it's easiest just to retain the directory structure and make sure that the `contrib/` folder is in your [load-path](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath).

That being said, I highly recommend using Emacs package management so you don't need to bother with manually manipulating package files.  Once set up, `M-x list-packages` then provides a very simple interface to find, install, update, and remove packages.  See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8182/how-to-use-org-plus-contrib) question for details about configuring package management for org-mode.  You may also want to use other repositories such as MELPA (instructions [here](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started)).

Comment: You'll need to add http://orgmode.org/elpa/ to your `package-archives` to get the `org-plus-contrib` package.