# org-mode ignore heading when exporting to latex

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have a problem where I want to structure my document visually with a heading but do not want it to actually execute a `\section{Fake Heading}` for the latex export. I imagine this would be customizable through an org mode property that I am unaware of.

```
 * Normal Heading
 ** Subheading 1
    baz
 * Fake Heading
   :PROPERTIES:
   :UNKNOWN_PROPERTY_NAME: t
   :END:
 ** Appendix A
    foo
 ** Appendix B
    bar
```

Desired result.

```
 \section{Normal Heading}
 \subsection{Subheading 1}
 baz

 \subsection{Appendix A}
 foo
 \subsection{Appendix B}
 bar
```

*Bonus*: it would be nice that it would only ignore the fake heading for latex export. The reason I need the fake heading in the first place is that there is a custom command in the latex `\documentclass{...}` I am using that generates an appendix `\makeAppendix` thus it is redundant to have a `\section{Appendix}`

Comment: There is a simple method that achieves something similar but not exactly what you want. If you select the region from Appendix A to the end of your example text Appendix A and B are exported as first-level headers. Don't know whether that bothers you. I know that this is not an answer, therefore I write this only as a comment.

Comment: Sadly that does not work for me because my document is much more complex than what have shown before. I have added to the question to show why that wouldn't work for me. Along that idea I think that using org sparse trees would be a possible workaround and then export.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to export content of subtrees without their headings?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9492/is-it-possible-to-export-content-of-subtrees-without-their-headings)

Answer (score 20):

For others who stumble upon this question, the following is available. As hinted to by yantar92, this is included in `ox-extra` which is included in the `org-plus-contrib` [elpa package](http://orgmode.org/elpa/9).

Headers can take an `:ignore:` tag, which excludes the heading upon export *while still including its contents*.

To make it work, add the following to your emacs setup (having installed `org-plus-contrib` [as described here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/8182/13253)):

```
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

How to make this only affect LaTeX export, I don't know.

Comment: You need the `titletoc` package mentioned in the manual at https://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-contents.html.

Comment: Just to add to this, you need to have the org mode repo added to your package lists for this to work. `ox-extra` is not included by default. If you're using `use-package` you basically do what this github issue says https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/597#issuecomment-352898477 and then in `:config` put @elfs answer.

Comment: `org-plus-contrib` is now outdated, use `org-contrib` instead: `(use-package org-contrib
    :config (require 'ox-extra)(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines)))`

Comment: This fails for me with error: `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil`

Answer (score 12):

Add this:

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
```

Then add the tag you specify:

```
* Fake heading :noexport:
```

Comment: This has the effect of commenting out the entire section under the `:noexport:`-tagged heading.

Comment: @AlexShroyer indeed, but I also landed on this question wanting exactly that ;)

Comment: One person's bug is another person's feature!

Comment: Note: I did not need to add an explicit `#+EXCLUDE_TAGS`. `:noexport:` seems to work by default.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a workaround that satisfies all my needs. It takes advantage of how org mode exports and that in latex you can have "multiline comments" or sections that it ignores https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex.

So I did the following and it works for me. Note that when exporting to other document formats (odt, html, markdown) it exports normally which is what I want.

```
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\iffalse % multiline comment
#+END_EXPORT

* Fake Heading

#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\fi
#+END_EXPORT

** Appendix A
   foo
** Appendix B
   bar
```

This results in the following latex code with comments out the latex section command.

```
 \iffalse
 \section{Fake Heading}
 \fi
 \subsection{Appendix A}
 foo
 \subsection{Appendix B}
 bar
```

Comment: That's terrible.  And by terrible I mean I'm going to use it right now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use org export filters for this purpose:

```
(defun yant/org-export-suppress-some-sections (data backend channel)
  "Do not put \\section for headlines with :NOSECEXPORT: tag."
 (when (eq backend 'latex)
  (let* ((parent (get-text-property (- (string-match "$" data) 2) :parent data))
     (headline (and parent (cadr parent)))
         (tags (and headline (plist-get headline :tags))))
    (when (member "NOSECEXPORT" tags)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`.*$" "" data)))))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-headline-functions 'yant/org-export-suppress-some-sections)
```

**EDIT:** Just found that `ox-extra` from org-plus-contrib provides the similar functionality. My solution seems to fit your question better though.

Answer (score 0):

You can retain folding by avoiding using a section at all and instead use a drawer. The contents of the drawer will still be exported but the drawer name will not.

Comment: If the content is after a section heading, org will assume that the drawer is part of that subtree, which may be unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to simply comment out the fake heading?
https://orgmode.org/manual/Comment-Lines.html

Comment: Then we would lose the ability to fold the headings to get a cleaner overview if needed though...