# Can't load org-drill package

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

So I've been trying to learn and use both Emacs and Org-mode for a while and it has been going pretty well but I am certainly a beginner in these topics including Emacs Lisp.

I found this really good-looking org package called org-drill and I've been struggling to get it running. I initially tried what it said in the installation manual, as in changing the org default variables and ticking the box where it says dril... that didn't work. I tried googling for a bit and I figured that maybe I don't have contrib packages installed. I tried doing what was given as the answer here: [org-plus-contrib and org with `require` or `use-package`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7890/org-plus-contrib-and-org-with-require-or-use-package)
again, to no avail. I tried manually searching for the package org-plus-contrib and I couldn't find it. In my init.el I have this:

```
;; ELPA
(setq package-user-dir (concat dotfiles-dir "elpa"))
(require 'package)
(dolist (source '(("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
              ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
              ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
              ("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")))
  (add-to-list 'package-archives source t))
(package-initialize)
```

So as I said, installing org-plus-contrib doesn't work. Neither does manually searching for it. Is it already installed? Am I missing something? Requiring org-drill in any manner doesn't work either. Do I have to manually include the contrib folder? I tried searching where it is but that didn't work either. I'm just not sure where to look next.
Any suggestions would be brilliant.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is poorly posed, and so risks being closed as unclear. You say nothing about what you have tried specifically, what you expected, and what specifically you saw happen instead. If you want helpful help then you owe it to *yourself* to provide the best possible description of the problem, which means providing *specifics* - in this case probably a step-by-step recipe of what you did.

Comment: Sorry, I was pretty frustrated when I wrote that. But yes, I'll edit it now, I should know better. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What error message  does `(require 'org-drill)` give you?

Comment: What happens when you do `M-x` `find-library` `RET` `org-drill` `RET`?

Comment: Check you directories under `~/.emacs.d/elpa`.  If you have sucessfully installed `org-plus-contrib` there should be directory starting with name and containing `org-drill.el`.  It is best if you have no other package installation of `org` mode present.

Comment: @erikstokes `eval-buffer: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, org-drill`

Comment: @itsjeyd `find-library-name: Can't find library org-drill`

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ok, I checked. I only have org which doesn't contain org-drill. But how do I get org-plus-contrib then?

Comment: In my set-up I merely customize `package-archives` to the list of archives and set nothing else for packages.  Then when I restart emacs, `list-packages` includes `org-plus-contrib` under the `org` archive.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I'm not sure what I did but the package suddenly appeared...